# How do I add this equation?

Tags: math-mode, equations

[image: This formula]

I tried using this, but am not getting the right results

```
\usepackage{dsfont}
...
\begin{equation}
    L_G_A_N(G, D_Y, X, Y) = \mathds{E}_y_~_P_{data}_(_y_)[log D_Y(y)] + \mathds{E}_x_~_P{data}_(_x_)[log(1 - D_Y(G(x)))]
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Try `L_{GAN}(G, D_Y, X, Y)` etc. That is, wrap longer subscript parts in curly brackets. And use `\sim{}` instead of `~`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem was on the right hand side of the equation. It looks like this https://imgur.com/d8TAgaZ. I want to get the pdata for x in line with the pdata for y

Comment: Instead of `\mathds{E}_y_~_P_{data}_(_y_)[log D_Y(y)]`, you should write `\mathds{E}_{y\sim P_{data}(y)}[\log D_Y(y)]`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Comment: And finally, you should probably write `\mathit{data}` instead of `{data}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
\[
\mathcal{L}_\mathrm{GAN}(G,D_Y,X,Y)=\mathbb{E}_{y \sim p_\mathrm{data}(y)}[\log D_Y(y)]
+\mathbb{E}_{x \sim p_\mathrm{data}(x)}[\log (1-D_Y(G(x)))]
\]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, have you seen the word "GAN". Why in the screenshot of the user "GAN" it is very compact than your "GAN". For the presence of the underscore? Same for "data". +1

Comment: The main document text in the image seems to be a `times` clone and the author uses the `\text` macro rather than `\mathrm` to render `GAN` and `data` the way you see it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply...You're right. My best regards.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Unicode math font, then you can do this:

```
$$
  ℒ_{\rm GAN}(G, D_Y, X, Y) = _{y ∼ p_{\rm data}(y)} [\log D_Y(y)] + 
                              _{x ∼ p_{\rm data}(x)} [\log(1 − D_Y (G(x))]
$$
```

Comment: Could you make this a full document?

Comment: @Anush For example in OpTeX format: insert before the example `\fontfam[lm]` and after it `\bye`. Becuase full document depends on used TeX format, I don't specify such format dependent thing. And I never use LaTeX format.